# Error In Java Keyword Search Tool

Tags: java, docx, wordsearch

I have patched the code including `e.printStackTrace()`. After I select a folder and hit the find button it does not display the error screen that was in the catch part before. However, nothing happens when I hit the find button. Here is the patched code:

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * Main.java
 *
 * Created on Jul 4, 2014, 8:19:21 AM
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Yağız
 */
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Boolean check = true;
    File[] filelist;
    /** Creates new form Main */
    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jFrame1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("CV Search"), this, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("title"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        label1.setText("Keyword:");

        jButton1.setText("Find");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Select Folder");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Select Folder Button
        try{
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            //File folder = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
            //filelist = folder.listFiles();
            //if(fc.getSelectedFile()==null){
            //    check = false;
            //}
            if(fc.getSelectedFile()==null){
                check = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                File folder = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                filelist = folder.listFiles();
                if( filelist.length == 0 ){
                // dialog: folder is empty
                    check = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = true;
                }
             }
        }catch(Exception e){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Folder!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Find button for finding the word in word documents in the selected folder
        String keyword = jTextField1.getText();
        if (! check ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Folder!");
            return;
        }    
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
        try
        {
            for( int i=0; i < filelist.length; i++){
                // maybe also .doc?
                if( filelist[i].getName().endsWith( ".docx" ) ) continue;

                //...
                XWPFDocument input = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filelist[i]));
                XWPFWordExtractor extract = new XWPFWordExtractor(input);
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(extract.getText());
                while(scan.hasNext())
                {
                    String word = scan.next();
                    if( keyword.equals(word) ) {
                        result.add(filelist[i].getName());
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
                //...
                if(result.isEmpty()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No match was found!");
                }
                else {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for( int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++){
                        sb.append( result.get(j) ).append( "\n" );
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString() );
                }

            }
         catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No keyword was found!");
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: A stack track would be helpful...

Comment: you can debug it to check where error occurs

Comment: @MadProgrammer Maybe not in this case `}catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No keyword was found!");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat So, then what's the `"Error" statement in J...` OP was posting?

Comment: @laune I am still working on that ;-)

Comment: @user3815419 The loop collecting matching file names is in error: only the last file name will appear in String s. Use a StringBuilder sb, do sb.append( result.get(i) ).append( "\n" ); and sb.toString() in the dialog invocation.

Comment: @user3815419 The test if(fc.getSelectedFile()==null) in jButton2ActionPerformed will never be true, because two lines above fc.getSelectedFile().getPath() would fail if it were true.

Comment: @user3815419  What's the point of the statement `if (check == false){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Folder!"); }` if you let the code continue, most likely with a filelist that is still null?

Comment: OK, I've done enough. The original problem can't be solved without complete code - too much depends on things not available in the original post.

Comment: Having tested only the "search" code, which works. I did hit a `InvalidFormatException` with one of my documents.  You might want to consider using `e.printStackTrace()` in your `catch` blocks to get a better idea of what the errors are...

Comment: @user3815419 And this loop accessing all elements of list `result` is incorrect, too: `for (int i=1; i<=result.size(); i++)` Jikes, nearly overlooked that...

Comment: @user3815419 And this one too: `for(int i=1; i<=filelist.length; i++)` Java basics!

Comment: @laune i tried to give an error screen if no folder was selected. since i'm new in java i make tons of mistakes so thanks for your help. what is wrong with the for loops?

Comment: @user3815419 Shouldn't the code make sure that a file in the folder is indeed a MS Word file before applying an XWPFWordExtractor?

Comment: @laune yes, i was just trying to see if the main program was working and was thinking of adding the adjustments after

Comment: @laune i have updated my question with the complete code.

Comment: You might update your code with my "patches" in the answer, and report how it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to patch my findings into the code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
//...

fc.showOpenDialog(null);
if(fc.getSelectedFile()==null){
    check = false;
} else {
    File folder = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    filelist = folder.listFiles();
    if( filelist.size() == 0 ){
        // dialog: folder is empty
        check = false;
    } else {
        check = true;
    }
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String keyword = jTextField1.getText();
    if (! check ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Folder!");
        return;
    }    
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        for( int i=0; i < filelist.length; i++){
            // maybe also .doc?
            if( ! filelist.get( i ).getName().endsWith( ".docx" ) ) continue;

            //...
            String word = scan.next();
            if( keyword.equals(word) ) {
                result.add(filelist[i].getName());
                break;
            }
            //...

         else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for( int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
                sb.append( result.get(i) ).append( "\n" );
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString() );
```

And add e.printStackTrace() in the catch blocks.

Comment: plus it doesn't give the "Select Folder!" error when an empty folder is selected

Comment: had some indentation mistakes corrected them, when a folder is not selected it gives the error. However when the search tool should be returning a file name(when i search a word in a file that i know it exists) it gives no match was found error. Moreover, when i searched a folder that had multiple formats of file with a docx in it and searched a word that existed in the docx it gave noclassdeffounderror: org/dom4j/DocumentException

Comment: added dom4j.jar to project library, now have invalid format exception:package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Comment: and finally does not return the file name when a known word is searched in a folder which contain only the corresponding document. @laune

Comment: Just found a typo: if( filelist.get( i ).getName().endsWith( ".docx" ) ) continue; => if( **!** filelist.get( i ).getName().endsWith( ".docx" ) ) continue; -- Note the '!'.

Comment: now i got the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument

Comment: I suggest that you separate issues. Close this Q when you are satisfied that you find a given word in a plain text file (",txt"). Create another question asking for help with searching for a word in a docx file, using a tiny Java program where you run into that error.